# .hide() div doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to close my comment section when someone clicks on a div with class 'cwindow'. I double checked the class/id and ran it on jsfiddle.net, and it works perfectly fine! Can someone help? Am I missing something obvious?

This is my html and css

```js
$(document)
  .ready(function() {
    $(".cwindow")
      .click(function() {
        $('#comment')
          .hide();
      });
  });
```

```css
#comment {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin-top: 15px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

.commentWrite {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  height: auto;
}

.cwindow {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #333;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 2px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

.cwindow i {
  padding-right: 3px;
}

.cwindow i:hover {
  cursor: url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/others/oth-6/oth589.cur), auto !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="comment">
  <div class="cwindow"><i class="xi xi-minus"></i><i class="xi xi-checkbox-blank"></i><i class="xi xi-close"></i></div>
  <s_rp_input_form>
    <div class="commentWrite"></div>
  </s_rp_input_form>
</div>
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6kotwd8/5/)**

Comment: try `$(".cwindow").on('click'...`

Comment: @AravindS and that would help why?

Comment: try $('body').on('click','.cwindow'),function(){$('#comment').hide();});

Comment: Since he is using jquery version `jquery/3.3.1` @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: The problem is that hes code is working, But the cwindow is only half height of #comment. Look here http://jsfiddle.net/h6kotwd8/18/

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, altered some styles in your css

```css
#comment {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin-top: 15px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 100px;
}

.commentWrite {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  height: auto;
}

.cwindow {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #333;
  margin: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  right: 5%;
  width: 10px;
}

.cwindow i {
  padding-right: 3px;
}

.cwindow i:hover {
  cursor: url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/others/oth-6/oth589.cur), auto !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cwindow").click(function() {
      $('#comment').hide();
    });
  });
</script>

<div id="comment">
  <div class="cwindow"><i class="xi xi-minus"></i><i class="xi xi-checkbox-blank"></i><i class="xi xi-close">close</i></div>
  <s_rp_input_form>
    <div class="commentWrite"></div>
  </s_rp_input_form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.cwindow` is in top of `#comment` and event only work in this area. [image: see this image]

Answer (score -1):

```css
#comment { border: 1px solid #333; margin-top: 15px; position: relative; z-index: 3; }
.commentWrite { padding: 10px 20px; height: auto;}
.cwindow { font-size: 12px; color: #333; text-align: right; margin: 2px; position: relative; z-index: 5; }
.cwindow i {padding-right: 3px; }
.cwindow i:hover {cursor: url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/others/oth-6/oth589.cur), auto !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".cwindow").click(function () {
        $('#comment').hide();
    });
});
</script>
<div class="cwindow">
       <div id="comment">
     <i class="xi xi-minus"></i><i class="xi xi-checkbox-blank"></i><i class="xi xi-close"></i></div>
         <s_rp_input_form>
         <div class="commentWrite"></div>
         </s_rp_input_form></div>
```

I wrapped your class "comment" with the div "cwindow" and then it worked. Hope that solves your problem.

[Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6kotwd8/7/)

EDIT: I notice now that your class is currently sitting in the top right hand corner. If you click there within the box it closes it.

Comment: If this is an answer and not just a comment, I believe it would be best if you should some proof of concept. Else people could just answer, "I did something else and now it works"